# Mvimdiff launches with vertical split on far right

Tags: vimdiff, git

I'm trying to integrate [mvimdiff](https://github.com/Angles/some-scripts/blob/master/bin/mvimdiff) into my workflow - but when I launch it via:

```
git difftool <filename>
```

I'm getting a wonky layout like this:

```
_________________________
|                    |   |
|                    |   |
|                    |   |
|         A          | B |
|                    |   |
|                    |   |
|____________________|___|
```

I've got a double monitor setup, so I figured it might be keying into the wider available display area? Is there any way I can specify it's resolution on startup so that it has a better chance of correctly splitting the window?

Comment: Do you have `'noequalalways'` set?

Comment: @tommcdo nope, I'll give that a whirl

Comment: No, don't, I was suspecting that was the problem :)

Comment: If you `<c-w>=` does that fix the layout?

Comment: i could take a look, but i've eloped with emacs/magit...